# Get the count of words in TinyMCE with Word Count plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4, django-tinymce

I wanna get the count of words in the textarea and make changes to my users account based on the number of words.  For example: a person writes 1000 words and its credibility goes up in the account 
    (I use Django)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>

    <script>
      tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
        plugins: "wordcount",
        toolbar: "wordcount"
      });
```

I Use this But I got an error : `TypeError: tinymce.activeEditor is null`

```
var wordcount = tinymce.activeEditor.plugins.wordcount;

console.log(wordcount.body.getWordCount());
console.log(wordcount.body.getCharacterCount());
console.log(wordcount.body.getCharacterCountWithoutSpaces());

console.log(wordcount.selection.getWordCount());
console.log(wordcount.selection.getCharacterCount());
console.log(wordcount.selection.getCharacterCountWithoutSpaces());
```

**

```
  </head>

  <body myFunction()>
    <form method="post">
      <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

    enter code here
```

Comment: Seems most of these tags may be irrelevant. Are you simply needing a way to count words in a string in python?

Comment: I've edited the tags :)

Comment: If would probably be more appropriate to do the word counting in python when the server receives the form data, rather than calculated in page and then used to modify account data. The reason being that it is easy for a user to modify the script in their browser to send any number they like  rather than basing it off the word count

Answer (score 0):

The API call `tinymce.activeEditor` only works when there is an "active" editor on the page.  Depending on when you are running your code there may not be an "active" editor at that exact time.

When you first run `tinymce.init({})` it takes TinyMCE some time to finish its initialization so until that happens there is no "active" editor.  Without seeing running code it will be hard to tell you definitively why you are getting the error you reference but most often I see that when people try to interact with TinyMCE either...

- **before** the editor has finished initializing
- **after** the editor was removed from the page